# Sort number in antd Table

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to sort a number column... I tried the normal sorting method but the result is not correct.

```
 const columns = [
      {
        title: 'NPI',
        dataIndex: 'NPI',
        key: 'NPI',
        sorter: (a, b) => a.NPI.localeCompare(b.NPI),
        render: (val, record) => <div title={'NPI: ' + val} className="text_overlap">{val}
            </div>
      }];
```

[image: the reslut]
the result I got after sorting is given in the image.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below login to sort your number, In the below example, I am sorting according to the name, age, and address.

you can see the age logic and according to that, you can manipulate your code.

```
import { Table } from 'antd';

const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    filters: [
      {
        text: 'Joe',
        value: 'Joe',
      },
      {
        text: 'Jim',
        value: 'Jim',
      },
      {
        text: 'Submenu',
        value: 'Submenu',
        children: [
          {
            text: 'Green',
            value: 'Green',
          },
          {
            text: 'Black',
            value: 'Black',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
    // specify the condition of filtering result
    // here is that finding the name started with `value`
    onFilter: (value, record) => record.name.indexOf(value) === 0,
    sorter: (a, b) => a.name.length - b.name.length,
    sortDirections: ['descend'],
  },
  {
    title: 'Age',
    dataIndex: 'age',
    defaultSortOrder: 'descend',
    sorter: (a, b) => a.age - b.age,
  },
  {
    title: 'Address',
    dataIndex: 'address',
    filters: [
      {
        text: 'London',
        value: 'London',
      },
      {
        text: 'New York',
        value: 'New York',
      },
    ],
    filterMultiple: false,
    onFilter: (value, record) => record.address.indexOf(value) === 0,
    sorter: (a, b) => a.address.length - b.address.length,
    sortDirections: ['descend', 'ascend'],
  },
];

const data = [
  {
    key: '1',
    name: 'John Brown',
    age: 32,
    address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    name: 'Jim Green',
    age: 42,
    address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
  },
  {
    key: '3',
    name: 'Joe Black',
    age: 32,
    address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
  },
  {
    key: '4',
    name: 'Jim Red',
    age: 32,
    address: 'London No. 2 Lake Park',
  },
];

function onChange(pagination, filters, sorter, extra) {
  console.log('params', pagination, filters, sorter, extra);
}

ReactDOM.render(<Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} onChange={onChange} />, mountNode);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const columns = [
      {
        title: 'NPI',
        dataIndex: 'NPI',
        key: 'NPI',
        sorter: (a, b) => a.NPI - b.NPI,
        render: (val, record) => <div title={'NPI: ' + val} className="text_overlap">{val}
            </div>
      }];
```

When debugged ,if NPI is a character/string convert it into number(integer) ; and then sort using  `sorter: (a, b) => a.NPI - b.NPI`